# Kubuntu 14.10, .zshenv is sourced twice

Tags: kubuntu, zsh, kdm

I have added some directories into `$PATH` variable in my `~/.zshenv` conf file. After reboot I noticed that these paths are appeared twice. I tried to print call stacks and got the following:

```
.zshenv sourced by
18385:/bin/zsh /etc/kde4/kdm/Xsession /usr/bin/startkde
 2158:  -:0
 1438:    kdm
    1:      /sbin/init

.zshenv sourced by
22143:/bin/zsh
20858:  /usr/bin/yakuake -session 10d5e3636b000141388223100000058160027_1415750006_832059
18385:    upstart --user
 2158:      -:0
 1438:        kdm
    1:          /sbin/init
```

So, the second one is ok, as it was caused by opening yakuake, where I was checking `$PATH` variable. But the first call is not clear for me. Why does `/etc/kde4/kdm/Xsession` try to load user's configuration? What is the reason and what is the best way to avoid `$PATH` duplication?

**Please don't suggest workarounds like wrapping the contents of `.zshenv` into checks for first run (aka include guards)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `/etc/kde4/kdm/Xsession` actually is used to load some of the user's shell configurations, it actually does *not* load `~/.zshenv` explicitly (although a comment mentions that it is loaded). `~/.zshenv` (as well as `/etc/zshenv`) are loaded automatically everytime a `zsh` starts up, this cannot be overridden. And as `/etc/kde4/kdm/Xsession` is run with your login shell - in your case `zsh` - `~/.zshenv` is loaded, too, no matter what actually is done in `/etc/kde4/kdm/Xsession`.

And `/etc/kde4/kdm/Xsession` tries to load the user's configuration so that it is available to programs that are started via means other than command line shell (KDE menu, autostart, desktop icon, etc.).

---

As for preventing `$PATH` duplication this should do the trick: Instead of using something like `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/my/path/here:/another/path`, use

```
new_paths=(/usr/local/bin /my/path/here /another/path)
path=($path ${new_path:|path})
```

`new_path` is an array of the paths you want to add. `path` is the array version of `PATH`, it has the same content but as actual array instead of colon-separated list. `${new_path:|path}` is substituted by an array of the elements in `new_path` that are not already in `path`.